# Maven Dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, classpath

**DISCLAIMER:**  Please refrain from submitting suggestions how this architecture should be changed, I am not in a position to change it.  I am in a new job trying to figure how things work, making visible architectural changes is not a variable nor is it within the scope of this post.  Thanks

**BODY:**  I am relatively new to `Maven` and I am currently struggling trying to figure out how `Eclipse` builds the list of `Maven Dependencies` for a project.  My Eclipse workspace conforms to the following layout:

```
workspace
  |
  |--maven
  |    |
  |    |--pom.xml (super pom)
  |
  |--proj_1
  |    |
  |    |--pom.xml (parent->relativePath=../maven/pom.xml)
  |    |
  |    |--src
  |
  |--proj_2
  |    |
  |    |--pom.xml (parent->relativePath=../maven/pom.xml)
  |    |
  |    |--src
  ...
  |
  |--proj_n
       |
       |--pom.xml (parent->relativePath=../maven/pom.xml)
       |
       |--src
```

where each node under *workspace* is an Eclipse project.  When looking at the Eclipse `Package Explorer`, the presence of `pom.xml` (I think) triggers the creation of a library bundle named `Maven Dependencies` with jars that make it into that project's `classpath`.

What I do not understand, however, if how Eclipse extracts the list of necessary referenced jars out of the hierarchy of pom.xml files.  E.g. I see a *foobar.jar* listed in my Maven Dependencies but no such entry is present in either that project's pom.xml nor in the super pom it references.  I need to make some changes to the classpath but I can't take the jars directly out of the Maven Dependencies (like I could out of the regular Eclipse `Referenced Libraries`) which leads me to think it needs to be done in the poms some place.

Please help me understand how the pom.xml hierarchy translates into the Eclipse classpath of referenced libraries.

Comment: First i would suggest tomove the pom.xml from 'maven/pom.xml' into '../pom.xml' which simplifies all other poms. Which means you can remove the relative tag.

Comment: i am in a new job trying to figure how things work, making visible architectural changes is not a variable nor is it within the scope of this post

Comment: @amphibient It's okay to discuss issues not directly related to your question. With regards to `foobar.jar`: Maven dependencies aren't just the files listed in your poms, but their transitive dependencies as well--that's kind of the point of Maven. Without knowing anything about what you're *actually* doing, it's impossible to speculate where `foobar.jar` is coming from other than that.

Comment: so, are `transitive dependencies` what Maven infers by reading the `import` statements in my java source files?

Comment: @amphibient : no, it reads them from the dependencies of your defined dependencies etc.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato -- where would those "defined dependencies" be?  i did not design this architecture, i am trying to figure how it works

Comment: @amphibient : that's a rather large topic, I invite you to read [Maven's documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html).

Comment: a very simple answer to my question would be, for example:  `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 0):

You should not be referencing parent `pom.xml` files directly, they should just be referred at the top of your children `pom.xml` files like so. Notice that there is no *relative* path anywhere in this configuration.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.yourcompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-parent</artifactId>
    <version>your-version</version>
</parent>
```

You will see lots of `.jar` files that are not directly referenced in the parent `pom.xml` nor the children `pom.xml`. This is normal, these are called **transient** dependencies. In other words they are dependencies of your dependencies.

You never make *changes to the classpath* with Maven, you just manipulate the `<dependency/>` stanzas and Maven builds the classpath that you need for you. If you are doing this manually you are doing it wrong. Which from some of the other statements, you probably have other things fundamentally wrong as well, because of some of the terminology you are using, Idiomatic Maven doesn't work off *relative paths* for `pom.xml` inheritance for one thing. But we can't tell because you didn't actually post how you are actually configuring your *parent* `pom.xml`.

Read up on the [`maven-dependency-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/plugin-info.html) it can produce this:

```
com.xx.xxxpreferences:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
+- com.xx.xxx:common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.5:compile
|  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:4.2.0:compile
|  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
|  |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
|  |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
|  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
|  |  +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12:compile
|  |  |  \- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.15:compile
|  |  \- org.swinglabs:pdf-renderer:jar:1.0.5:compile
|  +- com.xx.xxx:exceptions:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  |  \- struts:struts:jar:1.1:compile
|  |     +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |     +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
|  |     +- struts:struts-legacy:jar:1.1:compile
|  |     +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
|  |     +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.0:compile
|  |     +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile
|  |     +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0:compile
|  |     +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.1.4:compile
|  |     +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.7:compile
|  |     \- javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0:compile
|  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.5.0-b01:compile
|  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
|  \- com.netcharts:pro:jar:0.1:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.0.1:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.0:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.2.1:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.2.1:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.2.1:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.1.3:compile
|  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
+- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.4:compile
|  \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
+- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile
+- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
|  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
\- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0:compile
```

Then come back with some specific questions to get specific answers.

Comment: see the DISCLAIMER i just added to the top of the post

Comment: @amphibient no body is saying you have to change it, I am saying you don't understand it or that it is mis-configured to begin with. If it is mis-configured to begin with you will either have to change to be standard Maven practices, or you will have to learn to be a Maven expert and be able to configure all the non-standard stuff. *With the incorrect terminology you are using, and without specific actual `pom.xml` files nobody is going to be able to help you directly.* Good Luck.

Comment: OK ...  a specific question would be, given `foobar.jar` in my `Maven Dependencies`, how do I trace what requires it to be in the depencency list, i.e. there must be something somewhere that is requiring it so what series of steps would you take to determine the origin?

Comment: I already told you the answer to that, *"Read up on the maven-dependency-plugin and then come back with some specific questions to get specific answers."*

Comment: RE:  "Maven doesn't work off relative paths for pom.xml inheritance for one thing. But we can't tell because you didn't actually post how you are actually configuring your parent pom.xml."  again, i did not design this.  it came to me when i checked it out of the source control.  i am just trying to figure out how it works by getting specific answers rather than digging through the doc for it, and then put the pieces together, which is basically how my learning process works, as opposed to most ppl who do it the opposite way.  my brain is wired differently

Comment: **the specific answer is unless you post the actual pom.xml files with how they parent pom is declared you won't be able to get any help, you are asking questions out of context with the incorrect terminology, read up on it, then ask specific questions based on you r holes in your understanding** Your learning process is at odds with the charter of stackoverflow unfortunately, because no one here is a mindreader.

Comment: if you don't do some research and amend the incorrect terminology and incorrect *assumptions*, this will be closed : *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." There are already 2 close votes, it only takes 5, and the you will **have** edit your question to show you can actually understand any solutions or answers.

Comment: hey Jarrod, a very simple answer to my question would be:  `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: hey, @amphibient a better answer is the one I gave, because you figured it out yourself. Teach to fish ...